# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type error

Tags: c#

After i connected my database to my program, i would like to use it (I want to show the name on the header like "Welcome,[UserName]"). But I get this error, does anyone know how to fix it?

p.s I'm still new to C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["auth_user"] == null)
        {
            Cart.Visible = false;
            AuthUserName.Visible = false;
            EditProfile.Visible = false;
            Logout.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AuthUserName.Visible = true;
            AuthUserName.Text = "Welcome, " + ((User)Session["auth_user"]).Name;
            LoginBtn.Visible = false;
            AuthUserName.Visible = true;

            if (((User)Session["auth_user"]).Role == "Admin")
            {
                ManageProduct.Visible = true;
                ManageProduct.Visible = true;
                Report.Visible = true;
            }
            EditProfile.Visible = true;
            Logout.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is type of `((User)Session["auth_user"]).Role`?

Comment: Your question has two examples of using the `==` operator. The first has `null` as the right-hand-side operand, which is comparable to any nullable type. So most likely you are getting the error at `((User)Session["auth_user"]).Role == "Admin"`, and if so it's because the `Role` property is not a `string` instance. Which is exactly what the error message is telling you. You need to provide an operand that is valid for the `==` operator. See marked duplicate.

Comment: For future reference, please read the introductory material on the site before you post another question. Be sure to pay close attention to the [mcve] and [ask] pages, especially. In addition to making sure you provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, make sure that you include _the exact text_ of any error message that occurs. And of course, search the site first for such error messages (optionally, remove any identifiers unique to your code to improve the chances of a match in the search).